# Can I just copy the libraries built in ARM to Windows (x86) in order to cross compile a source code to ARM?

Tags: cross-compilation, arm, c++

Regarding cross compiling an external library to ARM. Can I just copy the built libraries in ARM (e.g. raspberry pi) to Windows and link them in CMake in order to compile a source code to be deployed in ARM? Does sudo apt-get install  (e.g. lib_boost-all-dev) just installs prebuilt libraries? How do I copy the headers, library, and binaries so to transfer them in Windows for cross-compilation process?

(EDIT)

What I really want is to be able to cross compile PCL to Raspberry Pi in Windows. I already have a working cross compiler running in Windows. The problem is I'm having a hard time finding a cmake-able boost that supports the PCL library. So I resort to downloading the library directly in Pi (e.g. sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev). Does this download and installs prebuilt library for Boost? If so, I'm thinking that using this. Maybe I can transfer this to Windows instead. In order to complete the cross compilation process.

Comment: "binaries" usually means executable files, while you most likely refer to "libraries" or "object" files. you may get better responses if you edit your question (and title) to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do the .dll files fall under the category of bin? Is the difference of the bin and lib that the bin contains the executable files while the lib contains the object files?

Comment: i've never heard about .dll used in linux, most probably you're talking about shared libraries (.so) files. and you're right about bin/lib difference, however it's not a must, someone can store anything in these folders.

Comment: If I cross compile a program using let's say the boost library, since it has nothing in the bin folder. Even if boost is not installed in Raspberry Pi, the executable file alone can run in Rpi? In libraries such as PCL which contains binaries, Raspberry Pi should have these binaries too in order to run?

Comment: sorry, no idea about boost and/or PCL =(

Comment: Make a distinction between compilation and linking and between static and dynamic libraries. Please restate the question, as it is not yet clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely maybe. In theory, there is nothing wrong with mixing cross compiled libraries and object files with native compiled, but, and this is a huge but, many complex projects will not work with different compilers. Your best chance for success is using the same compiler for both.